# ImageMagick convert cache directory

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, imagemagick

I was trying to use the convert command (OS X El Capitan) to convert a `.mod` video to `.mp4` and it quickly filled up my disk space and I had to <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to halt it.

But after restart, the disk space is still filled and I don't know where the cache, i.e. the half converted video is and I don't know how to delete it. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: `du -m -S / | sort -n -r | head -20`? This will at least list the sizes of the 20 largest directories mounted anywhere under /.

Answer (score 5):

**Updated Answer July 2023**

You can get the MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH with this command:

```
magic identify -list configure
```

It is listed near the end.

**Original Answer**

If you have set either of the two environment variables:

- MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH
- MAGICK_TMPDIR

then **ImageMagick** will use that directory for its temporary files. So, the first way to check is to run

```
env | grep -i MAGICK
```

and see if you have either set.

Failing that, or if you have no environment variables set, the easiest way I know to find where **ImageMagick** caches on disk is to turn on cache debugging and force **ImageMagick** to go to disk. So, we can turn on cache debugging with:

```
convert -debug cache ...
```

and we can force **ImageMagick** to go to disk by limiting the RAM it is allowed to use with:

```
convert -limit memory 100k ...
```

So, if we put that together:

```
convert -debug cache -limit memory 100k -size 1000x1000 xc:gray image.jpg

2016-05-19T13:25:46+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.4 Cache convert[46510]: cache.c/SetPixelCacheExtent/3500/Cache
extend gray[0] (/var/tmp/magick-46510CYSKWOdhlrym[3], disk, 8MB)
2016-05-19T13:25:46+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.4 Cache convert[46510]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3776/Cache
open gray[0] (/var/tmp/magick-46510CYSKWOdhlrym[-1], Map, 1000x1000 7.629MiB)
```

And, if you look carefully, you can see it is using `/var/tmp` on my Mac OSX - your system may be different, but this technique should show you what it is using.

Just as a test, I can set an environment variable and check **ImageMagick**  is using it:

```
# Tell IM where to cache stuff on disk
export MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH=/tmp/TEMPPATH

# Force an operation that will require caching
convert -debug cache -limit memory 100k -size 1000x1000 xc:gray image.jpg
2016-05-19T14:09:51+01:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.4 Cache convert[46584]: cache.c/SetPixelCacheExtent/3500/Cache
extend gray[0] (/tmp/TEMPPATH/magick-46584CivsEmIPjwv2[3], disk, 8MB)
2016-05-19T14:09:51+01:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.4 Cache convert[46584]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3776/Cache
open gray[0] (/tmp/TEMPPATH/magick-46584CivsEmIPjwv2[-1], Map, 1000x1000 7.629MiB)
```

**Keywords**: ImageMagick, environment variables, tmp, TEMPDIR, TEMPPATH, cache, disk, cache

Comment: Nice!

I also was looking for a way to find out why `cache resources exhausted` did hit me. (Set -limit memory via command line or change it in policy.xml, see: https://imagemagick.org/script/distribute-pixel-cache.php + https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php).

I was hard to find the default cache / temp directory. With your tip, I then ended up with this: `convert -debug cache -limit memory 1 null: null:` (which basically does nothing, except for showing the cache / temp directory).

Comment: @dpat I noticed your upvote and revisited the answer some 7 years after posting it. I have added a new method at the top that is somewhat easier.

Comment: Thank you very much! (And this is why I upvote even old questions / answers). Still: `identify -list configure` does not show `MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH` (at least) on my Linux system. So I still do not know where the default cache directory is when nothing is set.